# hive insert into query from CLI not working

Tags: hive, hiveql

I'm trying to insert into statement from CLI but getting following error. If I run the same query in hive prompt records are getting inserted. Any help would appreciated. I'm  using hive 2.x version.

```
hive -e "insert into table dim.mpp_dim_count (run_date ,run_type , count1,count2 ,dup_check_all_dim ,fact_dim_sk_match ) values ('05-04-2019','before',100,100,'Y','Y')"
```

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10293]: Unable to create temp file
>   for insert values AlreadyExistsException(message:Table
>   Values__Tmp__Table__1 already exists.)

Comment: What do you mean by _"Hive prompt"_ -- the same `hive` CLI utility (legacy & deprecated fat client) you are using for batch execution, but in interactive mode? the `beeline`CLI utility (thin JDBC client)? some other interface e.g. Hue or DBeaver?

Comment: What kind of table is that: standard or ACID?